# Website not zooming properly on most browsers, Most of the elements gets misplaced

Tags: html, css, web, zooming

I am building a website at the moment using HTML and CSS.

I have a small problem related to zooming. When the page is zoomed out most of the elements get messed up and out of place.

Browsers used:

- Google Chrome
- Safari
- Opera

More over when viewed from Safari on a 27" screen it becomes even worst.

**index.html**

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <title>Arrow-TvSeries - Home</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <meta property="fb:admins" content="{793705343}"/>
    </head>     
    <body>
    <center>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <div id="fb-root"></div>
                    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
                      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=80504353315";
                      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
                    <div id="fb-root"></div>
                        <script>
                          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                            // init the FB JS SDK
                            FB.init({
                              appId      : '793705343',                                 // App ID from the app dashboard
                              channelUrl : '//www.arrow-tvseries.com/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
                              status     : true,                                    // Check Facebook Login status
                              xfbml      : true                                     // Look for social plugins on the page
                              cookie      : true,                                   // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                              oauth       : true                                    // enable OAuth 2.0
                            });

                            // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
                          };
                          // Load the SDK asyncchronously
                          (function(d, s, id){
                             var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                             js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                           }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
                        </script>

                        <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                        xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
                        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<!--website-->
                    <div id="hood_image">
                            <br/><br/><br/></br></br></br><img src="images/oli_arrow4.png" align="right"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sitewrapper">
                        <div id="header"></div>
                        <div id="line"></div>
                        <div id="menu">
                            <br><a href="index.html">Home</a> | <a href="cast.html">Cast</a> | <a href="episodes.html">Episodes</a>
                        </div>
                <!--content-->
                        <div id="content">
                            <div id="episodecontent">
                                <table border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <img id="episodeimg" src="images/Next-Episode.png"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p style="color: white"><b>Title:</b> Home Invasion<br/><b>Date:</b> 24th April 2013</p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div id="division1">
                                <p>After a violent shipwreck, billionaire playboy Oliver Queen was 
                                missing and presumed dead for five years before being discovered 
                                alive on a remote island in the Pacific. When he returns home to 
                                Starling City, his devoted mother Moira, much-beloved sister Thea, 
                                and best friend Tommy welcome him home, but they sense Oliver has 
                                been changed by his ordeal on the island. While Oliver hides the 
                                truth about the man he's become, he desperately wants to make amends 
                                for the actions he took as the boy he was. Most particularly, he 
                                seeks reconciliation with his former girlfriend, Laurel Lance.</p><br/>

                                <p>As Oliver reconnects with those closest to him, he secretly creates 
                                the persona of Arrow a vigilante to right the wrongs of his family, 
                                fight the ills of society and restore Starling City to its former glory. 
                                By day, Oliver plays the role of a wealthy, carefree and careless 
                                philanderer he used to be - flanked by his devoted chauffeur/bodyguard, 
                                John Diggle - while carefully concealing the secret identity he turns 
                                to under the cover of darkness. However, Laurel's father, Detective 
                                Quentin Lance, is determined to arrest the vigilante operating in his 
                                city. Meanwhile, Oliver's own mother, Moira, knows much more about the 
                                deadly shipwreck than she has let on and is more ruthless than he 
                                could ever imagine.</p><br/>

                                <p style="font-size: 20px"><b>I n t r o d u c t i o n</b></p><br/>

                                <p>At the beginning of each episode, with the exception of "Pilot", the 
                                first episode of the series, a voiceover of Oliver Queen describes 
                                briefly the hardships that Oliver faced on Lian Yu. He states that 
                                as he returned, he set out to fulfill his father's dying wish.</p><br/>

                                <p>"My name is Oliver Queen. For five years I was stranded on an 
                                island with only one goal: survive. Now I will fulfill my father's 
                                dying wish. To use the list of names he left me and bring down those 
                                who are poisoning my city. To do this, I must become someone else. 
                                I must become... something else."</p>

                                <div id="video" align="middle">
                                    <iframe width="640" height="360" 
                                        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xZrFSsc6CpI?autoplay=1" 
                                        frameborder="1" allowfullscreen>
                                    </iframe>
                                    <!--?autoplay=1-->
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                                        google_ad_client = "ca-pub-8938167182852335";
                                        /* Home paga bottom */
                                        google_ad_slot = "9919170802";
                                        google_ad_width = 468;
                                        google_ad_height = 60;
                                        //-->
                                    </script>
                                    <script type="text/javascript"
                                        src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
                                    </script>
                                </div>
                                <div style="float: right; font-size: 9px;">
                                    <p><br/><br/>Most of the information about this Tv-Show is taken from <a href="http://http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2193021/?ref_=sr_1" target="new">IMDB.COM</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="division2">
                                <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.arrow-tvseries.com" data-width="200" 
                                    data-num-posts="10" data-colorscheme="dark">
                                </div>
                                <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.arrow-tvseries.com" data-send="false" 
                                    data-width="220" data-show-faces="true" data-font="arial">
                                </div><br/>
                                <div><br/>
                                    <p><b>You may also like:</b></p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                                        google_ad_client = "ca-pub-8938167182852335";
                                        /* First Ad */
                                        google_ad_slot = "7105305203";
                                        google_ad_width = 120;
                                        google_ad_height = 600;
                                        //-->
                                    </script>
                                    <script type="text/javascript"
                                    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
                                    </script>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <br/><br/><a href="http://www.imdb.com"><img src="images/imdb.png" alt="IMDB" width="100" /></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
```

**style.css**

```
a:link    {color:#fff;} /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#fff;} /* visited link */
a:hover   {color:#2e6402;} /* mouse over link */
a:active  {color:#fff;} /* selected link */

#table{
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
z-index: 100;
}

#header{
background-position: center;
position: relative;
background-image:url('images/logo_bg.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
border-radius: 25px;
height: 331px;
width: 1300px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
z-index: -3;
/*border:2px solid;*/
display:block;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#line{
width: 1290px;
height: auto;
background-color: white;
padding-top: 1px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

body{
background-color: black;
}

#sitewrapper{
width: 1300px;
height: 100%;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-right: auto;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

p{
text-align: justify;
font-family: arial;
padding-left: 0px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
color: white;
}

p2{
text-align: justify;
font-family: arial;
padding-left: 0px;
color: green;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#menu{
width: 1250px;
height: auto;
color: white;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 100px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
font-size: 120%;
/*border:2px solid;*/
text-align: right;
font-family: arial;
z-index: 31;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#episodeimg{
width: 250px;
float: left;
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 10px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#episodecontent{
width: 55%;
float: auto;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#hood_image{
float: left;
width: 30%;
height: auto;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
padding-left: 0px;
}

#content{
float: right;
width: 85%;
position: absolute;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
z-index: 5;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
/*border:2px solid;*/
}

#division1{
position: relative;
float: left;
height: 100%;
width: 700px;
color: white;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-left: 20%;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
z-index: 30;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
/*border:2px solid;*/
}

#division2{
float: right;
height: 100%;
width: 20%;
/*padding-top: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;*/
color: white;
border:2px solid;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
z-index: 1000;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

#video{
padding-top: 50px;
padding-left: 0%;
padding-right: 0%;
padding-bottom: 100px;
/*border:2px solid;*/
}

#footer{
/*background-color: red;*/
height: 10px;
width: 100%;
color: black;
background-color: white;
display:block;
}
```

**Link to this website:**

www.arrow-tvseries.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things to think about here. `#sitewrapper`needs to have `position:relative` as you want `#content` to be positioned absolute to position it in relation to its parent element and not the document. This will change around your layout a bit.

Next part is that use use `width: 85%` on `#content`. This limits and pushes the facebook integration around. Consider setting it to 100% instead. This will make the facebook box float to the right of the text.

There are many different ways to layout and position elements and this might not be an optimal solution, these changes should make it not move around when zoomed (tested in chrome).

There are also some other things you might want to consider. Try validate the css at http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ and it will point you to some errors.

Comment: Have you tried adding this in your head? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">